# Finding the URL for live snapshot on Honeywell HBL6GR2

Tags: ip-camera, honeywell

I'm trying to find the URL for the live snapshot on a new Honeywell HBL6GR2 camera I am evaluating. I need to be able to pull the image as a jpg from a URL such as:

`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/image.jpg`

I was told by Honeywell this was possible but can find nothing in the documentation ([here](https://www.security.honeywell.com/-/media/Security/Resources/Honeywell_Video_documents/HBL6GR2/800-23496_H4L6GR2-HBL6GR2-HM4L8GR1-HMBL8GR1_User_Guide-pdf.pdf)), and their tech support has been useless as I bought direct and not through a "dealer."

I've found pages such as these and tried all combinations of URLs to get a JPG with no success:

https://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=Honeywell
http://www.camera-sdk.com/p_183-how-to-connect-to-your-honeywell-ip-camera-onvif.html

I can access the admin portal fine, but need a direct link to the live image on the camera (a custom port will be needed also, but that can wait).

How can I go about finding this URL (if it even exists)? I can't imagine this camera doesn't support this.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to figure this out is to install `Onvif Device Manager` and `Wireshark`.

Add your device to `Onvif Device Manager` with `Wireshark` running and then search the `Wireshark` for `GetSnapshotUriResponse`. This will give you the URL of the snapshot if it is indeed supported by the device

Answer (score -1):

The standard is ONVIF. Per their documentation:

ONVIF (Open Network Video Interface Forum) is a global standard for the interoperability of IP-based physical security products.
You can enable or disable ONVIF authentication on the Setup > Network Setup > Connection > ONVIF page.

Try this:

https://www.onvif.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmers_Guide-1.pdf